# Drush field-clone with specified label

Tags: 7, entities, drush

The following command clones the field with the same label.

```
drush field-clone field_tags newtags
```

[image]

As you see, the cloned field has the same title **Tags**.

So how can I clone the existing field with desired label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the help for this command I'd say it is not possible:

```
$ drush help field-clone
Clone a field and all its instances.

Examples:
 field-clone tags labels                   Copy 'tags' field into a new field 'labels' field which has same 
                                           instances.                                                       
 open `field-clone tags labels`            Clone field and then open field edit forms for refinement.

Arguments:
 source_field_name                         Name of field that will be cloned 
 target_field_name                         Name of new, cloned field.
```

**Edit**: [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/85) can confirm it.

But you can always go to **Manage Fields**, edit the new field and change its name.

Comment: I edited the answer to add a link to a Drush issue requesting the label option and a confirmation that it doesn't exists.